# Are variables scoped to view by same method name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have page1 controller with these methods:

```
def index
  @myvar1 = 'var1'
end

def show
  @myvar2 = 'var2'
end
```

And have related index.html.erb and show.html.erb views.  It is not possible to use @myvar2 in the index view right?  It is scoped by the show method, which provides the show view.

Trying to use @myvar2 in the index view is out of scope because @myvar2 doesn't even exist at that point?

Comment: Why do you want to use `@myvar2` in `index` method? Can you provide a bit of context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, but you can use a `before_action` to set variables that will be available for both

```
before_action :set_var_three

def index
  @myvar1 = 'var1'
end

def show
  @myvar2 = 'var2'
end

private

def set_var_three
  @myvar3 = 'var3'
end
```